# Why aren't clusters of F-15 or SR-71 engines used for a boost stage for rockets?

Tags: launch, rockets, design-alternative, booster-flyback

A cluster of say 8 F-15 or SR-71 engines in my mind could make a viable first stage for a small rocket. Second they can land the stage back to the ground and if my guess is right they could go to up 50,000 to 70,000 feet and a respectable Mach 2 on the conservative side. This could provide a good point for a second stage fire in a low dynamic pressure zone using a vacuum only rocket engine. Unlike SpaceX, turn around time to use again would be one day or sooner.

Comment: A Pratt & Whitney F100-PW-220 turbofan engine has a thrust of 64.9 kN and 105.7 kN with afterburner. A Merlin 1D rocket engine has a sea-level thrust of 850 kN. A Falcon 9 uses 9 Merlin 1D engines. Do you really want a cluster of 118 or 73 turbofan engines?

Comment: I did say small rocket

Comment: Well, you did not say a tiny rocket. The concept of first stages with rocket engines did work very well for more than 70 years now. Tiny, small, medium and huge size first stages were build successfully using different engine sizes.

Answer (score 11):

**70,000 ft (~21 km) and Mach 2 (~700 m/s) is a pitiful booster stage**.

Consider the energy state (mass specific kinetic + potential energy of the rocket) during launch, this is a metric for measuring how well the booster performs. Here is one for a simulated launch vehicle (*close-ish to an expendable Falcon 9*) showing the booster stage at stage separation, and your proposed alternative:

[image: energy state diagram MJ]

(Personal work)

The black lines show equal energy contours ($\frac{MJ}{kg}$). The airbreathing first stage is only able to deliver the second stage with ***~20x less energy than a traditional booster stage***. Therefore your upper stage has a lot more work to do, good luck!

Comment: That plot nicely illustrates the misconceptions behind proposals for balloon launch, air launch, etc. Everyday activities rarely involve velocities greater than even 100 m/s. People unaccustomed to thinking about orbital dynamics seem to expect those lines to be mostly horizontal, when in fact they almost immediately become mostly vertical. Air-breathing engines are limited to a tiny area in the lower left corner, covering at most 2 or 3 of the ~20 contour lines. A suborbital hop to 100 km crosses barely more than 3 of them. And that's just a minimal, temporary <200 km orbit.

Comment: Thanks brendan. I guess my goal was to get the rocket out of the atmosphere because of the inherent drag and the more efficient vacume nozzle an engine could use. But yes its almoat too small a step be worth it. A ram rocket engine ie nasas GTX may ne much more usable.

Comment: The plot is incredible! I never saw such a brilliant illustration showing the huge difference between the air breathing stage 1 and a conventional stage 1 with rocket engines using a liquid oxidizer.

Comment: @TooTea great point, I'll fix that

Comment: If you have never researched and messed around with Nasas GTX spacecraft mod in orbital flight simulator. It shows how a largely horizontal ascent using a switchable ram / scram / rocket motor on a winged vehicle can get to space.   NASA did a full study but felt the scram heat management still needed work. So they dropped it.  I cant say enough about the flight sim module. Its shows in addition how to get into space, but you can do atmospheric skimming and going from the cape to perth takes a half ho

Comment: @user3660060 the problem isn't getting a vehicle to space with an air breathing engine, it's economically delivering payload to orbit. The GTX would have used air breathing as an act of desperation, accepted wisdom at the time being that SSTO was the only path for reuse, and SSTOs needing every last scrap of performance just to work. But a first stage is actually the easiest part of the launcher to recover and reuse, and staging gives you mass ratios that make an upper stage far easier to reuse than a SSTO, with more payload to orbit, all without wings and complex air-breathing engines.

Comment: Just noticed that this was supposed to be a Dragon: it's more consistent with the just-launched Starliner OFT-2, on an Atlas V. A Dragon would stage quite a bit sooner, around 2 km/s, at around 70 km altitude. Falcon 9 stages relatively early compared to more traditional rockets, which both allows the first stage to be recovered more easily and allows the upper stage to take more advantage of a dense propellant and common engine, with large propellant tanks and a high mass ratio to compensate for its relatively low specific impulse.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff Hmm good point, my sim is not smart enough to model recovery so it's just an expendable F9 I suppose

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff Yes a ssto would be more expensive than a can of aluminum or stainless. But fuel cost  is about the same..  its the same energy expenditure either way. Yes GTX pushed a fine margin of efficiency and required great accuracy to get to space.

Comment: Compared to everything else in a launch, fuel is basically free. A Falcon 9 burns [about $200k worth of propellants](https://www.quora.com/How-much-is-the-fuel-cost-of-launching-a-SpaceX-rocket) per mission, far less than the cost of even a single jet engine, let alone refurbishment. A design that has higher on-paper efficiency but more complexity is going to lead to higher lifecycle costs (testing, manufacture, refurbishment for reusables, etc.) that obliterate any gains from lower fuel cost.

Comment: @Cadence Worse, LOX is so cheap it makes fuel look expensive, and that's what air breathing saves. Craft like the proposed Skylon actually carried *additional* fuel (which had to be LH2, nothing else would work) to handle the added cooling demands of atmospheric flight. And today, Skylon wouldn't be able to compete against Falcon 9, let alone Starship...

Comment: The conclusion is not right. The second stage needs to deliver about twice the dv , making it a lot larger, but it doesn't need to be "20x more powerful". For rockets is dv that matters, not dE!

Comment: @asdfex good catch. As far as size / power multiplication needed for a sr71 at 100kg with horizontal take off  it comes closer to falcon 1 than one might think. There was a paper on using converted j58 engines as ram rocket engines.  Rated thrust 30,000 lbs each x= 60,000 lbs total. Falcon 1 = 100,000 lbs. Top speed at 85,000 feet. MACH 3.3 Oxygen weight saved due to using (ambient) 300/lbs a sec. x 2= 600 lbs a sec. At this point switch engines over to ram rocket. Speed at 85,000 feet. 2500 mph. Falcon 6500 mph. I dont have time to do all the calculations.  Its a guess falcon only 5 times pwr

Comment: Apart from your confusion of power and thrust and the relevance of thrust...the thrust figure you give for the SR-71's J58 engines is **static thrust**, not what it produces while cruising at Mach 3.3 at high altitude. Rocket engines don't lose performance with airspeed like jet engines do, and actually *gain* performance with altitude. And Falcon 1 did it with a kerosene-burning gas-generator engine that didn't even have regenerative cooling. And of course the SR-71 weighed more empty than the Falcon 1 did fully fueled, and could only carry 1.6 t of mission equipment...